# Using libgpiod and C++, how to wait for multiple line changes and get the changed value?

Tags: c++, gpio, libgpiod

Using C++ on a Raspberry Pi 4, I'm building a single routine called `monitor` to watch my GPIO lines and log changes for all lines. My simple code using `libgpiod`:

```
void monitor()
{
    const std::string chipname = "gpiochip0";         
    const std::vector<int> offsets = {4, 5}; // Lines 4 and 5 for testing
    try
    {
        gpiod::chip chip(chipname);
        gpiod::line_bulk lines;

        for (int offset : offsets)
        {
            auto line = chip.get_line(offset);
            line.request({"monitor", gpiod::line_request::EVENT_BOTH_EDGES, 0});
            lines.append(line);
        }

        while (true)
        {
            // Infinite waiting on all lines
            auto signals = lines.event_wait(std::chrono::nanoseconds(0)); 

            // STUCK HERE - How can I find out which line has changed and get its value and timestamp.
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

For the missing code, is there a way to find out which line has changed and get its current value?

If not, should I iterate between all lines? How can I find out which line has changed and its value?

**Version 1 Code:**

```
void monitor()
{
    const std::string chipname = "gpiochip0";         
    const std::vector<int> offsets = {4, 5}; // Lines 4 and 5 for testing
    try
    {
        gpiod::chip chip(chipname);
        gpiod::line_bulk lines;

        for (int offset : offsets)
        {
            auto line = chip.get_line(offset);
            line.request({"monitor", gpiod::line_request::EVENT_BOTH_EDGES, 0});
            lines.append(line);
        }

        while (true)
        {
            // Infinite waiting on all lines
            auto signals = lines.event_wait(std::chrono::nanoseconds(0)); 

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i) 
            {
                if (lines[i].event_wait(std::chrono::seconds(0))) 
                {
                    std::cout << "Change detected on GPIO line " << offsets[i] << std::endl;
                }
            }        
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: [event_wait()](https://www.lane-fu.com/linuxmirror/libgpiod/doc/html/classgpiod_1_1line.html#a88ab4f0716d05e1c3db030a7515a12d8) `Returns a line_bulk object containing lines on which events occurred.`

Comment: So, I get only those lines that changed, not all, correct? How can I get line number, value and event type?

Comment: @Mendes You have to read events for each line from a bulk in non-blocking mode.

Comment: @dimich, I've done what you've said - see Version 1 Code - now when running it waits for some line change and detects it, but logs it repeatedely, even when the line is not set anymore... Also, how can I make the first event_wait as blocking (0? -1?). Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Mendes In libgpiod before 2.0 you can wait for event on a bulk, then read lines state (e.g., all at once with `get_values()` on a bulk) and compare to previously saved state. Usually single hardware interrupt is allocated for entire bank, so it is not possible to distinguish which line triggered interrupt. Another method is to get descriptor for each line and wait for events on multiple descriptors with poll()/epoll_wait() etc. With this method you can wait events for lines in different banks.

Comment: @dimich _Usually single hardware interrupt is allocated for entire bank, so it is not possible to distinguish which line triggered interrupt._  The GPIO drivers in the kernel do that. If you ask for many lines to monitor, it will become several interrupts AFAIU (but again, the user will get the exact lines that triggered the interrupt. Otherwise such a hardware is kinda not so useful.

Comment: @0andriy It depends on hardware and driver. Probably you are right, in BCM2835 each GPIO line has it's own IRQ.

Comment: Haven't fount libgpiod 2.0 for Raspi. Is it the `libgpiod-dev` package?

Comment: @Mendes I'm not sure it is ported into official distro yet. See my answer below for `1.x`

Comment: This is better done with libgpiod v2, which contains an [example](https://github.com/brgl/libgpiod/blob/master/bindings/cxx/examples/watch_multiple_line_values.cpp) of doing just that.  AFAIAA that still hasn't been officially packaged for Pi OS, but it would be worth installing from source if that is an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

In `libgpiodcxx` versions 1.x `line_bulk::event_wait()` returns bulk of lines on which events occurred. `line_bulk` behaves like a collection, you can iterate it.

```cpp
    auto bulk = chip("gpiochip0", chip::OPEN_BY_NAME).get_lines({ 5, 6 });

    bulk.request({ "monitor",
        line_request::EVENT_BOTH_EDGES,
        line_request::FLAG_BIAS_PULL_UP });

    while (true) {
        // wait for events and get bulk of lines on which events occured
        auto changed = bulk.event_wait(std::chrono::seconds::max());
        // iterate lines in bulk
        for (const auto &line : changed) {
            std::cout << "Change detected on GPIO line " << line.offset() << std::endl;
            // read events occured on a line
            auto events = line.event_read_multiple();
            // iterate events
            for (const auto &event : events) {
                std::cout << "\ttype: " << event.event_type << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

Disclaimer: I'm not sure `event_wait(std::chrono::seconds::max())` is a good way for "infinite" blocking wait, but i haven't found proper documented method.

Comment: Documentation for **libgpiod v2** indicates a negative timeout will block indefinitely.  Same should apply to **v1**, even if it is not explicitly documented.

Comment: @KentGibson Thanks for mentioning that. I know about negative timeout for `event_wait()` C API but not sure how to make it with `std::chrono::duration` for C++ libgpiodcxx interface.

Comment: How about `std::chrono::seconds(-1)`?

Comment: @KentGibson In both versions `event_wait()` ends with `ppoll()` call. I haven't tried it by myself, but according to `ppoll()` documentation, *a negative timeout value for poll() is interpreted as an infinite timeout, a negative value expressed in *tmo_p results in an error from ppoll()*.

Comment: You are right - for **v1**, so `max()` is the best workaround for that :-(.  For **v2** the negative timeout gets converted to NULL where `ppoll()` is called, so that works as documented.  Not sure why that change wasn't backported to **v1** - perhaps it would be considered a breaking API change.